# Eclipse - PHP Project's Version Number

Tags: php, eclipse, version

This question is about Eclipse and the PHP plugin.

What I'm looking for is a simple thing that I can't find and it bother me a lot!
I try to get a Version Number of the current project I edit.

I explain myself, I make various website with the framework I have developped and I use many computer. So when I edit the framework, I sometimes update the other website, but not everytime (so I exclude the svn option or automatic update).

What I really like is to have an automatic Version Number, in any form (date, letter, number...) that can indicate me which code is the more recent and that I can include in every script file and possibly be refresh automatically ! 
example:

```
/** Version 2.0245796 
  * OR
  * Last Edit : 12/01/12 
**/
```

I don't really know if it's possible, I've find that the android sdk have such a thing, but not for PHP (can't find any information).

Comment: This is what versioning systems like svn are for, so you can use keywords like `$Rev$` that will be expanded to reflect current revision of file

Answer (score 0):

You can use templates in eclipse for this
    ${time}

U sould check out Configure>PHP>Editor>Templates

Comment: Kind of what I was looking for. But it's a definitive number, that you have to change manually.
Bu anyway, I learnt something with that, and it will be usefull for me later. Thanks.

Maybe if I combine this template with an automated task on Eclipse...